# Javascript detect when a property is re-declared with var keyword

Tags: javascript

Is there any way in Javascript of knowing when a property already defined gets re-declared as a variable, resulting in name collision? For example:

```
self.test = function() {
    return "this is a test";
};

var test = "another test";

console.log(test());
```

This code results in Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function.

I want to somehow detect this before the error happens.

I tried using Object.defineProperty to include a getter and setter and fire a callback when the property gets changed, but that only works if the variable is assigned, not when it is redeclared with var keyword.

As a last resource, I think using a regex parser in the JS code to detect these situations could work, but that doesn't seem like a good solution at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In you example `self.test` and `var test` are not in conflict. You would always need to write `self.test()` if you want to call that function.

Comment: @t.niese yes there are when it is executed in global.... self would be window...

Comment: @epascarello for the special case where `self` points to window (or another global object) then they are in conflict. If it is only about this special case then the OP should use `'use strict'` for all of the the scripts and wrap all code in a immediate invoced function.

Comment: @t.niese It's usual for `self` to be the global object. `window.self === window`.

Comment: @Oriol depends in which context js is used for browsers it is true unless `self` is used that way:`var self = this;`. But as I said, for that special case where `self` points to window the OP should use strict mode and iif. For all other cases a linter will help.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, to catch errors like this and many others, you should use a linter. I use [eslint](http://eslint.org/).

For the problem of redeclaring variables specifically, see the [const keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) if you're targeting modern browsers or want to use a transpiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting ES6, use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of var.

Re-declaring a let/const variable inside the same scope will give you an error. If declared in a different block, it will refer to a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly about detecting if property is redeclared. You can prevent property to be redeclared if this works for you in this case. You can use `Object.defineProperty` for that

```
var self = {};
Object.defineProperty(self, "test", {
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: function() {
    return "this is a test";
  }
});
```